# Memoir class and easy-todo package

Tags: packages, memoir, easy-todo

I have been working on a book and using the easy-todo package to keep track of things I need to do.

On another thread, it was recommended that I move to the memoir class because it has a lot of flexibility and, even after looking at it for a little while, I agree. But now I run into an error, apparently memoir is not compatible with easy-todo.

I get a missing \begin{document} error.

Below is a MWE.

Is there a work-around for this? Is there a similar package that works with memoir?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\title{Interesting words}
\author{Peter Flom}
\usepackage[enable]{easy-todo}


    \begin{document}
    \todo{Add more example sentences to USAGE including writing possible contemporary uses}
    \todo{Add more personal reasons why I love a word or where I found it, also more personal examples}
    \todo{Look at more about the frequency of the word, try to note why there was a peak}
    \todo{Add humor to anti-thesaurus}
    \todo{Move pronunciation to right after word}
    \todo{Learn Memoir}
    \todo{Write intros for all sections}

      \chapter{Introduction} \label{C:Intro}
       I learned to read at the usual age of 5. But I got hooked on reading at age 9 when I was sick and my mom got me \emph{A Wrinkle in Time} by Madeline L'Engle. I read it cover to cover. Then I started over. I was hooked. And I read everything. Sure, I read some kids' books but I also read some that were not meant for tweens. And I learned a lot of words. By 5th grade, my reading comprehension and vocabulary scores were off-the-charts. I love words.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Given that that package has not been updated since 2014 I'd be a bit iffy about it. Why not just use the todo package or fixme (I tend to use the latter as with the right setup fxnote can be used anywhere)

Comment: `easy-todo` attempts to use the `tocloft` package which should not be used with `memoir`. It then calls `\newlistof` in a manner that is incompatible wih `memoir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend `easy-todo` with `memoir` as it is relying on the `tocloft` package to do its list of. Eventhough `memoir` and `tocloft` started the same place, they are no longer fully compatible. Alo `easy-todo` has not neen updated since 2014.

I would recommend using the `todo` or `fixme` packages for notes. They both write in the margins do you don't fill up your text with notes for your self. The latter can even be configured to use the `marginnote` package to be able to write notes from everywhere (`todo` cannot do that).

That said, we can make it compile

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\title{Interesting words}
\author{Peter Flom}

\let\normalnewlistof\newlistof
\newcounter{todos}[part]
\renewcommand\newlistof[4][]{
  \normalnewlistof{listof#2}{#3}{#4}
}
\newlistentry[chapter]{todos}{lod}{0}

\usepackage[enable]{easy-todo}

\let\newlistof\normalnewlistof

\begin{document}
\todo{Add more example sentences to USAGE including writing possible contemporary uses}
\todo{Add more personal reasons why I love a word or where I found it, also more personal examples}
\todo{Look at more about the frequency of the word, try to note why there was a peak}
\todo{Add humor to anti-thesaurus}
\todo{Move pronunciation to right after word}
\todo{Learn Memoir}
\todo{Write intros for all sections}

\chapter{Introduction} \label{C:Intro}

I learned to read at the usual age of 5. But I got hooked on reading
at age 9 when I was sick and my mom got me \emph{A Wrinkle in Time} by
Madeline L'Engle. I read it cover to cover. Then I started over. I was
hooked. And I read everything. Sure, I read some kids' books but I
also read some that were not meant for tweens. And I learned a lot of
words. By 5th grade, my reading comprehension and vocabulary scores
were off-the-charts. I love words.

\end{document}
```